# ng-repeat not working on table with data recovered from post method

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I'm having some trouble trying to display a table with angularjs.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Registered On</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="s in users">
            <td>{{s.UserName}}</td>
            <td>{{s.UserEmail}}</td>
            <td>{{s.RegisterDate}}</td>
            <td class="td-actions text-right">
                <button type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-info">
                    <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-success">
                    <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-danger">
                    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It's just a simple table to display this data:

```
var user = (from c in userService.GetAll()
            select new
            {
                UserName = c.UserName,
                RegisterDate = c.RegisterDate,
                UserEmail = c.UserEmail
            }).ToList();

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { user = user });
return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And i get the data on angular controller:

```
$scope.GetData = function () {
   $http.post('@Url.Action("GetData")').then(function (result) {
        if (result.data != null && result.data != undefined) {                      
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.loading = true;
                users = result.data;
            }, 100);
        }
        else {
            loading = false;
        }
    })
}
```

And it's not working, no data are being show on table. I tried converting to json and just sending the object.

Also, i tried with this object, and it worked:

```
 $scope.groups = [
    { UserName: 'Test', UserEmail: 'a', Registered: '10/10/2020' },
    { UserName: 'Test', UserEmail: 'b', Registered: '10/10/2020' },
    { UserName: 'Test', UserEmail: 'c', Registered: '10/10/2020' },
    { UserName: 'Test', UserEmail: 'd', Registered: '10/10/2020' }
 ];
```

I've checked my object and it dont appear to be wrong formated, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data needs to be a property of $scope:

```
$scope.GetData = function () {
    $http.post('@Url.Action("GetData")').then(function (result) {
        $scope.loading = true;
        ̶u̶s̶e̶r̶s̶ ̶=̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶;̶
        $scope.users = result.data;
    })
}
```